# How to connect eclipse with docker

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, connect

My Eclipse version is Photon and docker version is 18.06.0-ce-mac70.

I want to execute the Docker command when I issue shell script commands on Eclipse.

But when I use a shell script, the `ls` command works well, but not `docker + command`

Error Stack trace  :

```
    `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
    "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at            java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:459)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:356)
    at dbUpdate.ShellCommander.shellCmd1(ShellCommander.java:36)
    at dbUpdate.ShellCommander.main(ShellCommander.java:29)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:270)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 6 more
```

And the code:

```
`package dbUpdate;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;`

    public class ShellCommander {



    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String carSSID;
    static String target;
    static String IPAddress;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String command = "docker ps";
        shellCmd1(command);
    }


    public static void shellCmd1(String command) throws Exception {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't search your `PATH` for commands. On my mac `docker` is in `/usr/local/bin`; I also would prefer a `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.exec`. Like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String command = "/usr/local/bin/docker ps";
    shellCmd1(command);
}

public static void shellCmd1(String command) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split("\\s+"));
    pb.inheritIO();
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
}
```